# Generate Android and IOS folder in react native directory with Yarn

Tags: react-native, cross-platform, yarnpkg

I have been having some trouble finding some straight answers in generating android and ios packages in a pre-existing react-native project.

`yarn start` works for me to view my project in on the web browser but I am trying to create an ios and android native project from this pre-existing website. Right now I have an empty template project that can be made using these commands on Mac Os after installing yarn:

```
yarn create react-app website
```

Now here is what my directory looks like. It is missing the android and ios directories that I will use and then run the command
[image]

```
 yarn ios
    or
 yarn android
```

Thanks I really appreciate the help. I have never worked with react-native so if the answer is obvious please explain anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn create react-app website
```

It will create website only, if you want to create react native app use

```
expo init AwesomeProject
```

or

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

or

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

---

If you want to give support of web inside your react-native app, you can use [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)